# Copying a property from a node is slow with a lot of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm migrating some properties in a labeled node and the query performance is very poor.

The old property is callerRef and the new property is code. There are 17m nodes that need to be updated that I want to process in batches. Absence of the code property on the entity indicates that it has not yet been upgraded.

```
profile match (e:Entity) where not has(e.code) with e limit 1000000 set e.key = e.callerKeyRef, e.code = e.callerRef;
```

There is one index in the Entity label and that is for code.

```
schema -l :Entity
Indexes
  ON :Entity(code) ONLINE
No constraints
```

The heap has 8gbs allocated running Neo4j 2.2.4. The problem, if I'm reading the plan right, is that ALL nodes in the label are being hit even though a limit clause is specified. I would have thought that in an unordered query where a limit is requested that processing would stop after the limit criteria is met.

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Properties set: 2000000
870891 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------+
|    Operator |     Rows |   DbHits | Identifiers |                    Other |
+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------+
| EmptyResult |        0 |        0 |             |                          |
| UpdateGraph |  1000000 |  6000000 |           e | PropertySet; PropertySet |
|       Eager |  1000000 |        0 |           e |                          |
|       Slice |  1000000 |        0 |           e |             {  AUTOINT0} |
|      Filter |  1000000 | 16990200 |           e |     NOT(hasProp(e.code)) |
| NodeByLabel | 16990200 | 16990201 |           e |                  :Entity |
+-------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------------------+

Total database accesses: 39980401
```

Am I missing something obvious? TIA

Comment: http://blog.bruggen.com/2015/07/loading-belgian-corporate-registry-into_20.html

has/not using columns in an index not supported until 2.3 so no optimization available?

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are supported only for `=` and `IN` (which basically are the same, because Cypher compiler transofrms all `=` operations in `IN`).

Neo4j is schema-less database. So, if there are no property - there are no index data. That why it needs to scan all nodes.

My suggestions:

- First step: add `code` property to all necessary nodes with some default "falsy" value
- Make update using `node.code = "none"` where clause

Answer (score 1):

It might be faster to first assign a new label, say `ToDo`, to all the nodes that have yet to be migrated:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)
WHERE NOT HAS (e.code)
SET e:ToDo;
```

Then, you can iteratively match 1000000 (or whatever) `ToDo` nodes at a time, removing the `ToDo` label after migrating each node:

```
MATCH (e:ToDo)
WITH e
LIMIT 1000000
SET e.key = e.callerKeyRef, e.code = e.callerRef
REMOVE e:ToDo;
```

Comment: As much as I'd like to think this would work, the 17million nodes will still be scanned _before_ the filter is applied. You have to read the profile above from the last entry to the first. Applying a label to 17 million nodes without batching the work (heap/deadlocks). Batching requires filtering - and we're back to the scan problem. If you run interactively, then updating batches means the scanning will become less and less. Caching the nodes helped after the first query helps, but this means you can run neo4j-shell -c in a loop without incurring the first load o/head

Comment: If this approach works as hoped, it will indeed access all 17 million nodes in the label-setting step (but breaking this step up into several smaller steps may access all 17 million every time anyway, so it may be faster to do this all at once). But, each of my proposed iterative 1 million-node steps would only access a million nodes at a time, not all 17 million. Please use profile, and let us know if the numbers look promising.